# How do I prevent httpwebrequest opening a new tcp connection for each PUT request?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, tcp, httpwebrequest

Whenever I have to PUT a json string to a server, I launch a new thread which has this code inside a class. It works fine, but the thing is that a TCP connection is opened for each request. When I checked the ServicePoint hashcode, its the same for each request.
When I looked in TCPView, I cannot find those connections - I think its because its opened and closed within ~50ms.
So, 2 questions -

1. Is it an issue if I leave it like this? A new request will be raised every second from the client.
2. How do I reuse the same TCP connection? What if I set ServicePoint.KeepAlive to true?

```
        public void SendRequest()
        {
            string sOutput="";
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_uri);
                myWebRequest.Timeout = Timeout;
                myWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = Timeout;
                myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                myWebRequest.Method = "PUT";
                myWebRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
                ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
                using (StreamWriter myStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(myWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    myStreamWriter.Write(_json);
                }
                using (HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        sOutput = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        sOutput = sOutput.Length == 0 ? myWebResponse.StatusDescription : sOutput;
                        ServicePoint currentServicePoint = myWebRequest.ServicePoint;
                        sOutput = currentServicePoint.GetHashCode().ToString();
                        currentServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 5;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                sOutput = Ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                callback?.Invoke(sOutput);
            }

        }
```

And here is how I launch the thread -

```
                    HTTPClass hTTPClass = new HTTPClass(cuURI, json, 5000, new MyCallback(ResultCallBack));
                    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(hTTPClass.SendRequest));
                    t.Start();
```

Here is the code after switching to HttpClient -

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task Write()
        {
            await WriteAsync(cuURI, json);

        }

private async Task WriteAsync(Uri uri, string json)
        {
            StringContent content = new StringContent(json,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

            await client.PutAsync(uri, content);
        }
```

Here is the wireshark trace screenshot which shows a new connection for every request.

[image]

The client is setting the FIN flag on its own, and the server is not sending a FIN from its side. What is happening is that I see a lot of connections in the TIME_WAIT state on the server side.

Comment: Regarding to documentation of [`HttpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8): _We don't recommend that you use `HttpWebRequest` for new development. Instead, use the [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) class._ `HttpClient` is reusing opened connections by default and fluently. But the best performance I reached with `HttpClient` is in .NET Core 3.1 (twice faster with multiple connections and supports HTTP/2 there).

Comment: And you spend a lot of processor time to `new Thread` creation. Try `Task.Run(() => hTTPClass.SendRequest());` instead.

Comment: Use HttpClientFactory : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: @aepot I switched to HttpClient, but still the same issue. Here is how I launch the task `await WriteAsync(cuURI, json);`. And this is the new async task: `private async Task<string> WriteAsync(Uri uri, string json)
        {
            StringContent content = new StringContent(json,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
            
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(uri,content))
            {
                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseContent;
            }
        }`

Comment: @Bruno It seems that the HttpClientFactory solves the issue when multiple HttpClients are instantiated in the application. But I am using only one client, after the suggestion by aepot, and I still have the issue.

Comment: Please edit the question with actual code.

Comment: try handle `IDisposable`: `using (var response = await client.PutAsync(uri, content)) { }`.

Comment: How is the caller method of `Write()` look like now?

Comment: @aepot I wrapped the PutAsync call in the using block. I don't understand how this affects the `Write()` method. Could you please clarify?

Comment: `using` for `PutAsync` properly makes free TCP connection exacly after it finished reading the response, makes it reusable as fast as possible. 2nd question about `Write()` can help me to understand how do you benchmarking this. I googled a lot and can't find that someone else has the same problem. Found one [for Linux](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22366) but there's benchmark log that shows it's working on Windows. Show how do you test it. Better the reproducible example that I can run on my side.

Comment: I found `ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime` Property has default value 100 seconds. Thus the connection may be reused in this period of time. Consider [`ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(Uri)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.findservicepoint?view=netframework-4.8) method.

Comment: @aepot Regarding MaxIdleTime, in the wireshark trace, the next request is within 2s of the previous one, so well within the 100s limit. Moreover, the issue is that as soon as the server sends status 200, the client acknowledges it and closes the connection (FIN, ACK). Regarding your point on reproducing at your end, I will try to send you something.

Comment: @aepot My apologies. I did not look in detail in the wireshark trace. In status 200 message from the server, it is setting the FIN flag, to which the client responds by closing it from its side too. Thanks for your help in pointing out that the HttpClient should be used, the code looks much cleaner now!